# Keep a minimum amount of cells, and still use commitEditingStyle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my TableView, I wanna display always at least 3 cells. If there is no cell, show 3 dummy cells, if there is one cell, display this one and 2 "dummy cells", of there are 2 cells, show them and one dummy cell, if there are 3 cells, show those 3, if there are 4, display those for, and so on.

So I implemented commitEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath, and it would work fine, if I wouldn't have

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if ([self.piggyBanks count]< 3) {
       return 3;
    }
    else{
        return [self.piggyBanks count];
    }
 }
```

As it expects one row less after deletion, it throws an exception, if I get from 3 to 2 or less cells (and therefore return 3 again in numberOfRowsForSection).

Any idea how I can possibly achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This forum post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/78110-uitableviewcontroller-after-delete-all-cells-add-new-cell.html) tracked me to a solution.

It's a bit complicated, maybe I'll try edsko's version lateron too, but I think that could also become a problem, as I would have to resort the cells..

The main problem was, when i have like 1 real cell, I have 2 dummy cells, so the last returned numberOfRows was 3. If I delete the one remaining cell, commitEditing expects 2 as the new result, but it would either be 3, if I just say, if my Arrays count is less than 3, return 3, or it would be 0, if I plain return the Arrays count.

So basically I did what the forum post suggested, but also created a property, storing the last returned numberOfRows. If numberOfRows gets called from commitEditing, I'll first return the last committed number -1, than reload the data, this time with the values I really need.

This will only work if I delete one row at a time, though, but my App's setup doesn't compliment deleting more than 1 row at a time.. So this will work for me.. Not as elegant, but possible..

I'll try edskos version lateron, seeing if that will work out easier..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `commitEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`, don't delete the row that is to be deleted if it will be replaced by a dummy row. Instead, tell the tableView to reload that particular row.